# Prevenir doble enviado durante x segundos en html

Tags: javascript, html

muchas gracias de antemano.

He creado un código sencillo de html donde inserto un dato en una base de datos. Como se va a hacer con un lector de códigos de barras quiero prevenir el doble enviado de ese dato sin querer por ello he creado una función que cambia el texto del botón y lo deja inutilizable durante 3segundos pero al crear esta función no esta haciéndome el action.php y no registra los datos

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function confirmEnviar() {
  miformulario.btnEnviar.disabled = true; 
  miformulario.btnEnviar.value = "Enviando...";
  setTimeout(function(){
    miformulario.btnEnviar.disabled = false;
    miformulario.btnEnviar.value = "Enviar";
  }, 3000);
  return false;
}

miformulario.btnEnviar.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    return confirmEnviar();
}, false);


    </script>
```

En este código anterior tengo la función que cambia el botón durante 3 segundos

```
<form name="miformulario" action="registrar.php" method="post" >

        <input type="text" name="codigo_beep" autofocus>
        <input type="submit" name="btnEnviar" value="BEEP" onclick="confirmEnviar()" >

    </form>
```

Y esto último el form donde al ejecutar el botón BEEP debe hacer el action registrar.php.

**Cabe destacar que si quito el evento onclick de mi botón si realiza el insertado de los datos, es decir, el problema esta en la función script no en el php**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una función que se llame en el evento click del botón beep. Esa función deshabilitará el botón y cambiará su texto a "enviando...". Luego se inicia un timeout con un valor de 3 segundos (3000 ms), cuando el contador finalice se llama la función `submit()` del formulario para enviarlo.

```js
function  deshabilitarBoton(){

 var boton = document.getElementsByName("btnEnviar")[0];
 boton.disabled = true;
 boton.value = "Enviando...";
 
setTimeout(()=>{
 var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario")
 .submit();

},3000);

}
```

```html
<form name="miformulario" id="formulario" action="registrar.php" method="post" >

        <input type="text" name="codigo_beep" autofocus>
        <input type="submit" onclick="deshabilitarBoton()" name="btnEnviar" value="BEEP">

    </form>
```

Comment: Si quito el return false luego el botón se queda deshabilitado

Comment: Pero ¿cuando se le da click al botón, debe desaparecer todo el contenido?

Comment: @Aprendiz Cuando tu haces click al botón BEEP, en este momento debe enviar los datos por que se le esta ejecutando un php que tiene un insert. Por defecto se elimina el contenido correcto, el problema es que por algún caso al hacer la función para deshabilitarlo durante 3segs no se ejecuta ese php

Comment: @Aprendiz En este caso no lo esta borrando el contenido. No se si es por que no se esta ejecutando el php con el insert ¿?

Comment: @BetaM sabes por que no ejecuta la función php?

Comment: Revisa la consola de js para saber si hay algún error al presionar el botón

Comment: @crrlos no da ningún tipo de fallo ni tampoco hace nada. No se como seguir respecto a tu respuesta

Comment: @amr07 Removiste el código js original y dejaste solamente el que coloqué en la respuesta?

Comment: @crrlos si correcto

Comment: @crrlos te invito a probarlo y verlo usted mismo

Comment: @crrlos su código inserta lo que yo pongo, pero no hace que el botón quede deshabilitado x tiempo para enviar un registro sin querer

Comment: Por eso mencioné que hay un error de diseño. Si estás usando el `action` en el formulario, cuando se presiona el botón `beep` se envía ese formulario y la página se recarga y así no se puede lograr tu objetivo de cambiar el texto del botón y deshabilitarlo 3 segundos. Para que funcione de la forma que quieres debes enviar esos datos usando ajax para evitar recargar la página. Con el código que te envié el botón sí se bloquea, solo que luego se recarga la página y se reinicia el estado. Pero no te permite enviar dos veces el mismo valor.

Comment: @crrlos he usado tu código y no bloquea el botón o al menos a mi

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106009/discussion-between-crrlos-and-amr07).

Comment: @crrlos Respuesta actualizada correctamente y funcionando. Muchas gracias